# Moodle no value in table but the query result count returns 1

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am using **Moodle 2.9.1**. I have a query to fetch the last record from the table:

My query as follows:

```
$qstndetails = $DB->get_record_sql('SELECT * FROM {epoll_questions} WHERE status=? AND courseid=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1',array(2,$curseId));
```

I am taking the count as

```
echo count($qstndetails);
```

I am getting the count as 1 in the case of result is there.

**But in the case of result is not there also I am getting count as 1.**

I had tried `print_r($qstndetails)` but nothing showing. But the **count show as 1**.

The expecting count is 0 when there is no result.

Why I am getting like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change the query to 
$qstndetails = $DB->get_**records**_sql('SELECT * FROM {epoll_questions} WHERE status=? AND courseid=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1',array(2,$curseId));

Now working!!

Answer (score 1):

When developing, always have debugging switched on. This would probably have displayed an error message for the first code. Go to site admin -> development -> debugging, then debug messages = developer and switch on display debug messages.

Also LIMIT isn't an SQL standard. Moodle works with several databases so try to keep the SQL generic.

Also I would suggest using named parameters rather than ?. It makes the code easier to read but they can also be used in any order.

and finally, you can use IGNORE_MULTIPLE to get the first record.

So the code should be something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM {epoll_questions}
        WHERE status = :status
        AND courseid = :courseid
        ORDER BY id DESC";
$params = array('status' => 2, 'courseid' => $curseid);
$qstndetails = $DB->get_record_sql($sql, $params, IGNORE_MULTIPLE);
```